# Node Hierarchy and active menu trails

Tags: routes, nodes

I'm trying to use Node Hierarchy module together with the Menu Block module to create blocks in different regions of my site.  My problems is that when a child path is active, the parent path doesn't highlight.

An example of what I want is the path http://example.com/exampleparent/childnode1

My main menu is on the left side of the screen, like so:

- Home
- **Example Parent**  <-- active parent
- About

And the child menu is on the right side of the screen, like so:

- **Child Node 1** <-- active child
- Child Node 2

But when I'm viewing the child node the parent isn't "active" (bold, in my example).

Is there an option I'm missing, or does the Menu Block module not work the way I think it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not that the modules failed to act correctly.  The problem was that the theme I was using did not have any CSS for the `active-trail` class that is provided.

To be thorough, there are two classes that get applied to menu items.  The `active` is only for the exact menu that you're at.  The `active-trail` class gets applied to all the parents of the current menu.